# Using Siddhi patterns to detect events that did not occur

Tags: wso2, pattern-matching, siddhi, wso2-cep

In CEP engine I am trying to do a pattern like

```
from s1 = SensorStream[level == 'A'] **NOT** -> s2 = SensorStream[level == 'B'] within 10 sec  
select s1.id as id1, s2.id as id2 insert into AlertStream
```

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25555714/using-siddhi-patterns-for-events-that-havent-happened) , but what I have is not a range...

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Marta,

Can't you use below approach. Is that what you want to achieve ?

from s1 = SensorStream[level != 'A'] -> s2 = SensorStream[level == 'B'] within 10 sec
select s1.id as id1, s2.id as id2 insert into AlertStream

Comment: No @Mohanadarshan, what I am trying to do is to detect absences. In the example I want to be able to detect that s1 = SensorStream[level == 'A'] occurred  and SensorStream[level == 'B']  did not occurred, within 10 sec.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been added to Siddhi 4.0 (currently under development) with the [PR#483](https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/pull/483). According to this implementation, your requirement can be achieved using the following query:

```
from s1 = SensorStream[level == 'A'] -> not SensorStream[level == 'B'] for 10 sec  
select s1.id as id
insert into AlertStream;
```

Note that the not pattern cannot have a stream reference `s2` because you cannt select the id of an event that is not arrived.

If you want to try Siddhi early access, follow the instructions given in this tutorial: [Siddhi 4.0.0 Early Access](http://www.javahelps.com/2017/01/siddhi-400-early-access.html)

For more samples, have a look at the [test cases](https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/tree/master/modules/siddhi-core/src/test/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/query/pattern/absent).